# When is $\lim_{b\to a} \int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^af(x)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, limits

An elementary question on Riemann - Integration:

Under what conditions on $f$ is the following true:

$$\lim_{b\to a} \int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^af(x)dx=0$$

If $f$ is bounded in $[a,b]$, then this is simple to prove.

But what is the most general condition on $f$ for which this holds?
Answers relating this to other types of integral (like Lebesgue, ...) are also welcome.

Taking the example of $ f(x) = {1\over x-a }$.

$ lim_{b\to a} lim_{t\to0} \int_{a+t}^b f(x) dx \to \infty$

but

$  lim_{t\to0}lim_{b\to a+t} \int_{a+t}^b f(x) dx \to 0 $

Enlighten me please.I'm pretty confused. The following questions are also related to this.
It would be really helpful if somebody can resolve this:

[Is there any notable difference between studying the Riemann integral over open intervals and studying it over closed intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461459/is-there-any-notable-difference-between-studying-the-riemann-integral-over-open/464512#464512)

[Why is the Riemann integral only defined on compact sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99753/why-is-the-riemann-integral-only-defined-on-compact-sets?lq=1)

[Is there any notable difference between studying the Riemann integral over open intervals and studying it over closed intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461459/is-there-any-notable-difference-between-studying-the-riemann-integral-over-open?lq=1)

Comment: If the Riemann integrals in question are defined at all, ...

Comment: I'm looking for a function like $ 1 \over x-a $

Comment: Such integrals are only defined as limits themselves, and then it can depend on which order you take the limits in, so there's no answer which is satisfying.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen for the function $1 \over x-a $ the function is not defined at $a$ but if we see intuitively the limit   diverges to infinity and at the same time the second inequality always holds.That's why I'm confused.

Comment: @AdamHughes Can you explain this for some examples like the one i've mentioned $1 \over x-a $ ?

Comment: Integrating (in the sense of Riemann) ${1\over x-a}$ requires you to treat

$$\int_a^b{dx\over x-a}=\lim_{t\to a}\int_t^b{dx\over x-a}$$

Which gives you $\lim_{t\to a^+}\log\left|{b-t\over t-a}\right|$ which is divergent, so you'd be taking $\lim_{b\to a}(\infty)$ which is nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

1. using Riemann definition:
   the function $x\to \frac 1{x-a}$ is not defined on $a$. How is defined the integral in such case?
2. using Lebesgue definition:
   if $f$ is integrable, then 
   $$
   \lim_{b\to a} \int_a^b f 
   = \lim_{b\to a} \int f1_{a\le x\le b}
   $$and using the dominated convergence theorem, the limit is 0.
3. if $f$ is not integrable and $\ge 0$, the terms of the sequence are all $\infty$, so will the limit.

Comment: Thank you for (2) and (3) . For (1) That's precisely the question i'm asking.We know that the function is not defined at $a$. So,is there a way to define $\int_a^b f(x) dx $ as an improper integral and then try to take the limit.

Comment: If you define the integral as the improper limit, anything can happen, basically. That's the whole problem with these things.